# Java Android studio - add new entry to API

Tags: java, android, api

need some help understanding how to make a connection with the API I've been provided in order to Add/update/delete an entry, but I think once I understand adding, I'll be able to figure out the other two.

I've already created a new activity with plain text fields that can be edited, but obviously I don't know how to add the functionality for it to add the entry on the website.

Here is the API documentation:
Get all students [GET] Returns all students in a JSON array. 
PARAM 1 apikey - the apikey given to you. 
URL http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/getallstudents.php?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY

Get one student [GET] Returns single student as a JSON object. 
PARAM 1 apikey - the apikey given to you. 
PARAM 2 studentnumber - the student number of the student you wish to retrieve. 
URL http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/getstudent.php?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY&studentnumber=A_STUDENTNUMBER

Add student [POST] Add a student to the database. 
PARAM 1 apikey - the apikey given to you. 
PARAM 2 json - a JSON object containing all key value pairs of a new student. 
URL http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/add.php

Update student [POST] Update an existing student. 
PARAM 1 apikey - the apikey given to you. 
PARAM 2 json - a JSON object containing ALL key value pairs of a student. 
URL http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/update.php

Delete student [POST] Delete an existing student. 
PARAM 1 apikey - the apikey given to you. 
PARAM 2 studentnumber - the student number of the student you wish to delete. 
URL http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/delete.php

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String [] personNames;
ArrayList<Person> allPerson = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    ListView personList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.personList);

    //make the button open a new activity with the form to add a new student
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewStudent.class));
        }
    });

    //http call
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://radikaldesign.co.uk/sandbox/studentapi/getallstudents.php?apikey=xxx");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String response = convertStreamToString(in);
    System.out.println("Server response = " + response);

    try {
        // declare a new json array and pass it the string response from the server
        // this will convert the string into a JSON array which we can then iterate
        // over using a loop
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        // instantiate the cheeseNames array and set the size
        // to the amount of cheese object returned by the server
        personNames = new String[jsonArray.length()];

        // use a for loop to iterate over the JSON array
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            // the following line of code will get the name of the cheese from the
            // current JSON object and store it in a string variable called name
            String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString();
            String gender = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("gender").toString();
            String dob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("dob").toString();
            String address = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("address").toString();
            String postcode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("postcode").toString();
            String studentnumber = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("studentNumber").toString();
            String coursetitle = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("courseTitle").toString();
            String startdate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("startDate").toString();
            String bursary = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("bursary").toString();
            String email = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("email").toString();
            // print to log cat
            System.out.println("name = " + name);

            Person c = new Person(name, gender, dob, address, postcode, studentnumber, coursetitle, startdate, bursary, email);
            allPerson.add(c);
            // add the name of the current cheese to the cheeseNames array
            personNames [i] = name;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, personNames);
    personList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    personList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long
                l) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selected " +
                    allPerson.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //declaring intent and sending it to the page you click on
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("person", allPerson.get(i));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

}

Still can't figure this out or find a way of doing it, 
any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: What does the log error say?

Comment: I don't get any errors - the functionality that I've done up to now works. I just don't understand how to add new functionality such as adding a new entry to the API like shown on the emulator here: https://imgur.com/a/Stzkmnp

Comment: pls. consider pasting the api directly into the question. links can be undependable and render this post unusable for others.

Comment: done - thought a screenshot would be fine but I pasted the API into the post